# How to get the look as in itunes to display list of files

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i wanted to display the list of files like it is done in itunes .how can it be done please help me out im a beginner
the screen shot is here[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CoverFlow API Apple uses is (I think) still private, there's open source implementations like [OpenFlow](http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/), there's lots of resources on how to get started with it if you dig around on Google.

Answer (score 4):

That thing you are referring to is called coverflow and there is open source library that provides such functionality

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary